# Wrap a Linq query in a try/catch block using a method declaration

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

So here is what I would like to be able to do.

```
var a = Item.CatchLog().Where(x=>x.Property=="value").Take(10);
```

or

```
var a = Item.CatchLog().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Property=="value");
```

or

```
var a = Item.CatchLog().Any(x=>x.Property=="value");
```

Essentially, I would like is for `CatchLog()` to basically wrap the execution of the query in a try catch, and `Debug.WriteLine()` the `Exception` and then `throw` it.

Any ideas on how I could implement something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to rewrite your statement, like so:

```
var a = Item.CatchLog(c => c.Where(x => x.Property=="value").Take(10));
```

If you allow that, you could write something like:

```
public static U CatchLog<T,U>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<IEnumerable<T>,U> method)
{
    try
    {
        return method(collection);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
         throw;
    }
}
```